Chart JS text centre in doughnut chart
I have a circle with text within my doughnut chart js, how can i centre the text, seems to be different position depending on screens.
  Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeDraw: function(chart) {
      
    var width = chart.chart.width,
      height = chart.chart.height,
      ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
     
    ctx.restore();

ctx.beginPath();
var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
ctx.arc(width/2,height/2,55,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = '#006072';
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.strokeStyle = '#CBE1EF';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
ctx.save();

     

    var text ="$" +  Math.round( round_number / Math.pow(10,zeroCount) ) + "M +",
      textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
      textY = height / 1.9;

    ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
    ctx.save();
  }
});


To center text within your doughnut chart in Chart.js, dynamically calculate the text position based on the canvas dimensions.

The text should drawn after defining textX and textY, ensuring correct placement.
The ctx.restore() and ctx.save() calls should be placed correctly to manage the context state.

Here is the updated code:
Chart.pluginService.register({

  
beforeDraw: function(chart) {
  var width = chart.chart.width,
      height = chart.chart.height,
      ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
  
  ctx.restore();

  // Set font size dynamically based on chart height
  var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
  ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
  
  // Draw the circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(width / 2, height / 2, 55, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#006072';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#CBE1EF';
  ctx.stroke();

  // Prepare the text
  var text = "$" + Math.round(round_number / Math.pow(10, zeroCount)) + "M +";

  // Measure text width to center it horizontally
  var textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;

  // Calculate the text's x and y coordinates
  var textX = (width - textWidth) / 2;
  var textY = (height / 2)
  
  // For exact verticle centring consider adjusting factor if necessary
  // var textY = (height / 2) + (fontSize * some_factor)

  // Set text color and fill text
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
  ctx.save();
}
});


hmm, looks a bit hight to me. not centre

Read your comments, my bad. thank you for your help
